# Java 8 predicate generic function is not accepting List of Integers

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have one filter Method using Predicate Interface to filter List on some conditions.

```
public static <T> List<T> filter(List<T> list,Predicate<T> predicate){
    List<T> result=new ArrayList<T>();
    for(T t:list){
        if(predicate.test(t)){
            result.add(t);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

I have one Integer array List as List arraIntegerList=Arrays.asList(1,2,3,3,4);

While calling above method it is giving compilation error.

```
System.out.println(filter(arraIntegerList,(int i)->(i>2)));
```

Why It is giving compilation error while same list with String is working fine.

Comment: Your method can be implemented simply as `return list.stream().filter(predicate).collect(Collectors.toList());` or, if it has to be an `ArrayList` you can use `return list.stream().filter(predicate).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to give the List a parameterized type, and the lambda's parameter must match the parameter of the List.

For example, this works :

```
List<Integer> arraIntegerList=Arrays.asList(1,2,3,3,4);
System.out.println(filter(arraIntegerList,(Integer i)->(i>2)));
```

Output :

```
[3, 3, 4]
```

As Stuart Marks commented, this also works :

```
List<Integer> arraIntegerList=Arrays.asList(1,2,3,3,4);
System.out.println(filter(arraIntegerList,i->(i>2)));
```

Comment: Thanks Eran.
I think issue was coming due to using (int) instead of using Integer to pass for Predicate method.

Comment: @NaveenGujjar Yes, my initial explanation was wrong, and I fixed it. The `List<Integer>` is also required.

Comment: You don't even need to declare `Integer` as the lambda parameter type. It'll be inferred correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The lambda parameter types must exactly match with the method description. Since `(int i)` doesn't match with the generic method description `filter(List<T> list,Predicate<T> predicate)`
and generics doesn't work with primitives. 
So you need to provide the parameterized type.

```
    System.out.println(filter(arraIntegerList, (Integer i) -> (i > 2)));
```

And you can let the compiler to infer the type though. In that case you can write -

```
    System.out.println(filter(arraIntegerList, i -> (i > 2)));
```